# Null Pointer Exception in simulated UNIX filesystem in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am currently trying to help a friend on their Java classwork, and as someone not intimately acquainted with Java, I have run into some trouble. The code I have is as follows:

**File Class**

```
public abstract class File {

private String name;
private Directory parent;
public File(String name){this.name=name;}
   Directory getParent(){return parent;}
  // String getPath(){}
}
```

**TextFile Class**

```
public class TextFile extends File{
private String content;
TextFile(String name, String content){ super(name); }
String getContent(){ return content;}
void setContent(String content){this.content=content;}
}
```

**Directory Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Directory extends File{
private ArrayList<File> children;
Directory(String name){super(name);}
void addChild(File f){children.add(f);}
ArrayList<File> getChildren(){ return children; }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Directory root = new Directory("/");
    Directory a = new Directory("a");

    if(a == null){
        System.out.println("A is null. Program will not continue.");
    }
    else{
    root.addChild(a);
    TextFile b = new TextFile("b", "hello world");
    }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I attempt to run the code, I get a null pointer exception at:

Directory.addChild(Directory.java:8)

Driver.main(Driver.java:12)

I cannot for the life of me think of why this exception is happening. I can't think why at any point `a` would be null. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your `Directory` class:

```
public class Directory extends File {
    private ArrayList<File> children;
    Directory(String name){ super(name); }
    void addChild(File f){ children.add(f); }
}
```

You never initialize `children`.

Try adding in the constructor:

```
children = new ArrayList<File>();
```

So the class would look like:

```
public class Directory extends File {

    private ArrayList<File> children;

    Directory(String name){
        super(name);
        children = new ArrayList<File>();
    }

    void addChild(File f){ children.add(f); }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just write:

```
private ArrayList<File> children = new ArrayList<File>();
```

In Java 7 and above you can simplify the constructor to just this:

```
new ArrayList<>()
```

The type is assumed to be the same.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I wish everyone could explain as good as you. I +1 u already ;)

Answer (score 3):

In `Directory`,

```
private ArrayList<File> children;
```

Declares an `ArrayList` but doesn't *initialize* it. You need something like

```
private ArrayList<File> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I would prefer coding to the [`List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) like

```
private List<File> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate `children` first.

```
private ArrayList<File> children = new ArrayList<File>
```